# How to build an animated accordion which works nicely on mobile devices? Pure JS or WebKit transform3d?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, accordion

I'm looking to build an animated accordion which will work well on mobile devices.

I already built one using `-webkit-transition: height 200ms ease;` but it was sluggish at best when viewed on a mobile device.

Now I'm thinking Pure JS or a hardware accelerated webkit transform3d solution. What do you think? Has anyone seen an example of this working perfectly on a mobile device?

Answer (score -1):

jQuery Mobile has an accordion but it's not animated: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html

I think that's honestly the best approach, start with a simple show/hide style accordian without animations, then use progressive enhancement to add transitions via the CSS transformations for modern mobile browsers that support them

Comment: I'd rather not use CSS `transitions` since they don't even look nice on my arguably modern iOS5 test device. If animating an accordion can't be done then so be it, but that seems unlikely given there are amazing examples of CSS `transforms` used for e.g. page transitions in e.g. JQM.

Comment: Sorry I meant CSS transforms, the idea is still the same though, make or use a very basic accordion that just does a simple show / hide and then enhance with css transformations for browsers that support them.

Comment: OK, use progressive enhancement, got it, thank you. Still don't know how to "add" an animated accordion using CSS transforms or JS for the browsers that do support it though.. :)

Comment: Sorry I interpreted your question as "what is a strategy for developing an accordion element for mobile" not "someone go search on Google for an accordion script and get back to me." You specifically ask for people's thoughts in your original question.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I wasn't being rude, I appreciate the advice of using progressive enhancement, I will be using that. However, I found this wasn't super-easily googled which is why I believe I asked for peoples thoughts and specifically examples of **successful** animated accordions for mobiles.